# Load HTML in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load different HTML in different DIV.

But the issue is only one page is loading, the other page is throwing an error.

The first div has a test page which has a Highchart and the second div has a Jquery data table.

It says Object doesn't support property or method 'highcharts' when I click on Tab 1.But When I comment Div 2 I get the high chart loaded.

Please advise.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"> <title></title> 
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>­
     <script type="text/javascript"src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

</head>
<body> <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
   <div id="tabs" style="width: 100%">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Alerts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Reports</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tab4">Management</a></li>

    </ul>

         <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function ()
 { $('#tabs').tabs({ collapsible: true, active: 1, event: 'mouseover' }); });

         </script>

    <div id="tab1">
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //alert("HI");
            $("#tab1").load("test.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
            });

            });

    </script>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
          <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tab2").load("employeedata.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });

       });
                </script>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        This is Tab 3 Content
    </div>
        <div id="tab4">
        This is Tab 4 Content
    </div>
</div></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you have highcharts loaded in tab 1. You should probably add highcharts to your main page instead of in the individual tab pages (test.html, employeedata.html, etc.)

Comment: Test.html page has all the high chart scripts and each page(test and Employeedata)  is running successfully individually with out any issues.

Comment: your partial page would have some script content which would be breaking in parent page where you are trying to load. Look again on it...